# Get value details in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need some help in getting the day based  array element in a multidimensional array in php.

Here's my array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 2 2013 [Name] => Abc Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 135 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 2 2013 [Name] => Cde Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 585 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 3 2013 [Name] => Sdf Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 123 )
        [3] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 3 2013 [Name] => Sdc Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 456 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 4 2013 [Name] => Fcd Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 789 )
        [5] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 4 2013 [Name] => Rfd Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 906 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 5 2013 [Name] => Vfd Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 567 )
        [7] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 6 2013 [Name] => Gfr Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 456 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 6 2013 [Name] => Dvh Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 343 ))
```

I want output for `Apr 3 2013` this day:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 3 2013 [Name] => Sdf Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 123 )
        [1] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 3 2013 [Name] => Sdc Starling [No] => 15616286[Duration] => 456 ))
```

Comment: You want to ***group arrays*** or you want to ***find only one group***?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$source=array(array("DOS"=>"Apr 3 2013","flag"=>"hit"),array("DOS"=>"Apr 4 2013","flag"=>"no hit"),array("DOS"=>"Apr 3 2013","flag"=>"hit"));
$cond="Apr 3 2013";
$result=array_filter($source,function($v)use($cond){
    return $v["DOS"]==$cond;
});
print_r($result);
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/Q09XY#v530)

---

Edit: [Live demo on your array](http://3v4l.org/4Su0B#v530)

Comment: my array is Array ( [0] => Array ( [DOS] => Apr 2 2013 [Nurse]....

Comment: @Neal Yes, the code above is just for demonstration. Reading your question, only `DOS` should be concerned, the other value can be left as is.

Comment: @Neal I've added a demo with your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
if($key['DOS'] =='Apr 3 2013'){
print_r($arr[$key]);
}
}
```